# curl a file -> cgi (perl) as data collector?

Tags: perl, post, cgi

I am trying to write a data collector for linux machines over the web.  alas, I do not want my users to submit the information over email, but abuse my web server as a recipient collector, too.  I thought this would be easy, but I am not getting results.

say my client has a file "results.txt" and I want the client to communicate this to my cgi server perl script.  I thought if my client runs

```
    `$ curl -X POST -d @results.txt http://mycollectorsite/my-collector.pl`
```

or

```
    `$ curl -X GET -d @results.txt http://mycollectorsite/my-collector.pl`
```

I should see the results in my perl cgi script.

the script runs fine.  alas, when I am looking at what my-collector.pl receives in its %ENV and @STDIN , I see that the results.txt file does not appear in it.

obviously, I am doing something stupid here, but it eludes me what it is.

[adding code example]

Code:

Comment: What is the content of results.txt? Does it match the MIME type being sent?

Comment: It will be much easier for us to identify the why your code doesn't do what you want if you post the code so we can see what it's doing. Ideally, you should post a minimal failing case - something complete enough that we can run it ourselves and not more than 20-30 lines long (probably less in this case), which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I landed on this old and found this answer in the man page of Mac curl.

```
 -F, --form <name=content>
     (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has 
     pressed the submit button. This causes  curl  to  POST data  using
     the  Content-Type  multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388.

     Example: to send an image to a server, where 'profile' is the name 
     of the form-field to which portrait.jpg will be the input:

        curl -F profile=@portrait.jpg https://example.com/upload.cgi

     To read content from stdin instead of a file, use - as the 
     filename. This goes for both @ and < constructs. Unfortunately it 
     does  not support  reading the file from a named pipe or similar, 
     as it needs the full size before the transfer starts.

     You can also tell curl what Content-Type to use by using 'type=', 
     in a manner similar to:

       curl -F "web=@index.html;type=text/html" example.com

     or

       curl -F "name=daniel;type=text/foo" example.com
```

So what worked for me to send a file of text (html form field name results) and one html form text field (name email_address) is like so:

```
curl -F "results=@results.txt;type=text/ascii" -F "email_address=auser@emailservice.com" http://mycollectorsite/my-collector.cgi
```

Here is a form / cgi processing tutor that works fine with this curl send command: https://www.sitepoint.com/uploading-files-cgi-perl/